# How can I upload build artifacts to s3 bucket from codepipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a codepipeline which trigger a few codebuild projects in different stage. In my codebuild project i have this configuration to

```
#codebuild.yml

Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
...
Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
        BuildSpec: buildspec.yml

# buildspec.yml

version: 0.2
phases:
   ...
artifacts:
                name: test-result
                files:
                  - '**/*'
                  - '*'
```

I this configuration it specifies the artifact and use `CODEPIPELINE` as artifact type. so in codepipeline, how can I upload them to s3 bucket?

What I can think of is to write another codebuild project and use `aws s3` command line to upload the files. But it is too manual. Is there an automatic way to do the job?

The build artifact includes test results and I'd like to upload the test results regardless previous failure or not. Is it possible to achieve this in codepipeline?

Answer (score 3):

> how can I upload them to s3 bucket?

There are two ways. One you already pointed out - use CB action (same or different) to copy files to S3 using AWS CLI.

Second, is to use [S3 deploy action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/integrations-action-type.html#w2aac12b9c13b7). This allows you to deploy zipped or unzipped artifact to your destination bucket.

Comment: How can I make sure the action is always run regardless whether the previous action failed? Thanks.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao I don't think you can. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/concepts-how-it-works.html): "A failure, when an action in a stage does not complete successfully. The revision does not transition to the next action in the stage or the next stage in the pipeline". So if one action failes, the subsequent does not execute. You can can have actions in parallel, so if your test action does not depend on other action you can run it as a parallel action.